# Must Have Either a Return Type or Callback as Last Argument Retrofit2 Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, retrofit2

I am currently working on an app for my martial arts organization, and within the app I want it to display a map with pins showing where each of the martial arts dojos are located in my state.  I'm doing this using fragments, as in the app you access the map from the drawer toggle.  My `LocationFragment` extends `SupportMapFragment` and implements `OnMapReadyCallback`.  However, when I open the locations tab, the map begins to load and then crashes.  This is the error that comes through the Android Monitor:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PinsApiInterface.getStreams: Must have either a return type or Callback as last argument.
                                                       at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.methodError(RestMethodInfo.java:107)
                                                       at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseResponseType(RestMethodInfo.java:270)
                                                       at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.<init>(RestMethodInfo.java:97)
                                                       at retrofit.RestAdapter.getMethodInfo(RestAdapter.java:213)
                                                       at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:236)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
                                                       at $Proxy0.getStreams(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.mycompany.kfcomapplication.fragments.LocationFragment.onMapReady(LocationFragment.java:85)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                       at zu.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
                                                       at maps.ad.t$5.run(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I understand that the error has something to do with my PinsApiInterface.getStreams, which I access via Retrofit2, but I'm not sure how to fix the problem.  I was following along with the guys at Tutsplus and how they implemented a map into their zoo application (which the code I am looking at is found [here](https://github.com/PaulTR/GettingStartedWithAndroid/blob/master/Lesson%2018%20-%20Code%20Cleanup/app/src/main/java/com/tutsplus/zoo/fragments/ZooMapFragment.java)).  In their tutorial, they are using an older version of Retrofit that uses `public void success()` and `public void failure()` as overrides under their `PinsApiInterface.getStreams()`.  With Retrofit2, this has been changed to `onResponse()` and `onFailure()`. I've searched multiple different threads on how to fix this crash, but I haven't had any luck.  I was hoping that I could get some help on how to resolve this issue.  I'm pretty new to using Retrofit2 in Android, so any help would be much appreciated.  Below is the code for my `LocationFragment.java` and for my `PinsApiInterface.java`.
Here is `LocationFragment.java`:

```
public class LocationFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public static LocationFragment getInstance() {
        LocationFragment fragment = new LocationFragment();

        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        CameraPosition position = CameraPosition.builder()
                .target(new LatLng(42.921966,  -85.718533))
                .zoom( 16f )
                .bearing( 0.0f )
                .tilt( 0.0f )
                .build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position), null);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(42.921966,  -85.718533));
        options.title("KFCOM");
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
        googleMap.addMarker(options);

        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                return true;
            }
        });

        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/101ffbf7e1aed60b7caf7d3d5418bfde/raw/43b5d1fa6862fd1dce84044821cdf1a9d48b6ca2")
                .build();
        PinsApiInterface pinsApiInterface = adapter.create(PinsApiInterface.class );

        //This line is what is causing the crash.
        pinsApiInterface.getStreams(new Callback<List<Pin>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Pin>> pins, Response<List<Pin>> response) {
                if(!isAdded() || pins == null || pins.equals("") )
                {
                    return;
                }

                for( Pin pin : response.body()) {
                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position( new LatLng(pin.getLatitude(), pin.getLongitude()));
                    options.title(pin.getName());
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                    googleMap.addMarker(options);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Pin>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is `PinsApiInterface.java`:

```
public interface PinsApiInterface {
    @GET( "/Pins.json" )
    void getStreams(Callback<List<Pin>> callback );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing retrofit with retrofit2.  `RestAdapter` is Retrofit 1, but `Callback` with `onResponse` and `onError` is Retrofit2.

First, look at your dependencies in your gradle file, you are going to need the following --

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

and also remove any libs of the form -- 'com.squareup.retrofit...'.  That is pulling in the old library and part of why you did not get compile time errors when mixing the two.

For your service, callbacks are no longer specified, it has a new `Call` based interface.  `Call` allows you to choose synchronous vs asynchronous at the time you make the request instead of when you define it. --

```
public interface PinsApiInterface {
    @GET( "/Pins.json" )
    Call<List<Pin>> getStreams();
}
```

Replace this old retrofit code --

```
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/101ffbf7e1aed60b7caf7d3d5418bfde/raw/43b5d1fa6862fd1dce84044821cdf1a9d48b6ca2")
                .build();
PinsApiInterface pinsApiInterface = adapter.create(PinsApiInterface.class );
```

with the new method of building your service interface --

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/101ffbf7e1aed60b7caf7d3d5418bfde/raw/43b5d1fa6862fd1dce84044821cdf1a9d48b6ca2")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
PinsApiInterface pinsApiInterface = retrofit.create(PinsApiInterface.class);
```

finally, the new method of making an asynchronous call --

```
Call<List<Pin>> myCall = pinsApiInterface.getStreams();
myCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Pin>>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<List<Pin>> call, Response<List<Pin>> response) {
          // your response code
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<List<Pin>> call, Throwable t) {
         // your failure code
      }
});
```

Comment: Ah yeah, it looks like I did mix up Retrofit and Retrofit 2.  I see where my problem is now!  That seemed to fix the error that I was having.  Looks like the app is still crashing due to something that's wrong in my "for loop" within my onResponse code, but I'll hopefully get that sorted out.  Thanks!